# For a Bayes Classifier are actual outcome and classifier outcome independent?

Tags: probability, machine-learning, bayesian

For a Bayes Classifier defined as:
$$
h(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
1: Pr(Y=1 \mid X=x) > \eta \\
0: \text{Otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Is this true:
$$
Pr(Y=i, h(x) = j \mid X=x) = Pr(Y=i \mid X=x) * Pr(h(x) = j \mid X=x)
$$
That is are they conditionally independent?

Comment: I think where you have a slash you mean the vertical bar used in conditional probabilities? You can get that using `\mid`. For text such as "Otherwise" that shouldn't be italicized within a mathematical expression, you can use `\text{Otherwise}`. For an operator like $\operatorname{Pr}$, use `\operatorname{Pr}`.

Comment: Thanks, I have made the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h$ is constant given $X$. A constant random variable is independent of all random variables. Thus $h$ is independent of $Y$ given $X$.

Comment: I agree $h$ is constant given $X$. But, if the constant is one does it not imply that there is a high probability that $Y$ = 1?

Comment: @ShivTavker: It does. But this is already implied by $X=x$. You're not asking whether $h$ and $Y$ are independent, but whether they're independent given $X$. The constant $h(x)$ doesn't contain any information beyond the information contained in $X=x$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is it like I have correctly identified the distribution of $Y \mid X$, but still, the two events are tossing independent coins of the same bias?

Comment: @ShivTavker: I'm afraid I don't understand that analogy. It sounds more complicated to me than the situation at hand.

Comment: I think I got it!! Thanks for your help.